# controlled sequence vs associated sequence?

Tags: c++

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf :

> Common examples are UTF-8 (or other multibyte) files accessed through std::wfstream objects: the **controlled sequence** consists of wchar_t characters, but the **associated sequence** consists of bytes.

Though from the top of the page there are definitions of *controlled sequence* and *associated sequence*, but I can't still understand. What is the quoted text talking about? How do they relate to each other?

A primary explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *controlled character sequence* is the buffer managed by the `streambuf`. The *associated character sequence* is the data received from or send to an underlying data source such as an I/O device.

You can see the relation between the two sequences in the diagram in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf. For a reading streambuf, data is pulled from the *associated character sequence* to populate the buffer. For a writing streambuf, data is sent to the *associated character sequence*. In both cases, a code conversion may take place.